# Pattern Remove from string php

Tags: php, string

I have a string In the pattern

```
a:22:{s:10:"identifier";s:17:"12345678912345678";s:10:"URL";s:0:"";s:10:"profile";s:62:"https://www.xyz.com//";}
```

I want to remove the string count like s:10 or s:17 from this string so i can decode it in JSON

Comment: json_encode(unserialize($value))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not JSON and shouldn't hence be decoded as JSON. This is a serialized string using PHPs [`serialize()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function. To "decode" this string use the [`unserialize()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function of PHP.